# GAM - Smooth comparison with factor variables

Tags: multiple-comparisons, generalized-additive-model, splines, mgcv

I try to compare the splines for my 6 categories. To this end, first I tried the ordered factor approach and posted the result [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/349743/210294). This comparison is not sufficient for me since I would like to have pairwise comparisons.

1. To this end, first, by keeping the ordered factor approach, I thought that by changing the reference level, I can have the pairwise comparisons. I did this by changing the category names since I cannot relevel an ordered factor. Normally, when F is the reference level, if there is a significant difference between F and G5 (G5 as an example), I expect to have this significant difference also between G5 and F when G5 is the reference level. But it was not the case. I don't understand why.
2. Then I follow this [blog post](https://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/10/10/difference-splines-i/) and create pairwise comparisons. When I did the ordered factor approach, the differences were significant for F-G1P1 and F-G5P1 (See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/349743/210294)). Using the same model, I create the pairwise comparisons and my output is the following:
   [image]

The method says "Where the confidence interval excludes zero, we might infer significant differences between a pari of estimated smooths." This is not the case for my smooths. Why I don't get the same significant results as in my previous analysis where I use the ordered factor approach, F being the reference level?

Thank you in advance.